# Storing Argon2 hash in database

Tags: hash

This is how I am using Argon2:

```
step1 =  argon2.PasswordHasher(time_cost=16, memory_cost=2**15, parallelism=2,  
                              hash_len=32, salt_len=16, encoding = 'utf-8')   
step2 = step1.hash('password1')
print step2

# $argon2id$v=19$m=32768,t=16,p=2$vruz5GwPq3vNO9SOlf1O4w$ahmCvQcgB+MqUrWdYGLbLB4G7ZOGP5bgcYxaDM/AaLo
```

I am storing the output, so obtained in `step2`, as a single unit in one column with
character set `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.
I have no separate column for salt, since the `hash` already has it.

Is this a proper way to store Argon2 hash?

Comment: yes, The library parse it for you.